# Cannot uninstall OpenGeo Suite 3.0.2

Tags: boundless-suite

I cannot uninstall opengeo suite 3.0.2.    I tried uninstalling and it would timeout on me. So I deleted the directory and now it won't let me uninstall or reinstall.

My goal is to get OpenGeo 3.0.2 working with postgreSQL 9.1 and postGIS.   I had it working on Windows 8 (32 bit) and am now trying to move my data to Windows 8.1 (64 bit).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about support for a particular GIS product. This falls outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing OpenGeo 3.1 over it.